# Expected Moves vs Copies

Tags: c++11, destructor, move, copy-constructor

It is my understanding that move semantics can use move-constructors to elide what would otherwise be a copy.  For example, a function returning a (perhaps) large data structure can now return by value, and the move constructor will be used to avoid a copy.

My question is this: is the compiler *required* to not copy when this is possible?  It doesn't seem to be the case.  In that case, wouldn't the following code have "implementation-defined" semantics?

```
static const int INVALID_HANDLE = 0xFFFFFFFF;

class HandleHolder {
    int m_handle;
public:
    explicit HandleHolder(int handle) : m_handle(handle) {}
    HandleHolder(HandleHolder& hh) {
        m_handle = hh.m_handle;
    }
    HandleHolder(HandleHolder&& hh) : m_handle(INVALID_HANDLE) {
        swap(m_handle, hh.m_handle);
    }
    ~HandleHolder() noexcept {
        if (m_handle != INVALID_HANDLE) {
            destroy_the_handle_object(m_handle);
        }
    }
};
```

Say then we make a function:

```
HandleHolder make_hh(int handle) { return HandleHolder(handle); }
```

Which constructor is called?  I would expect the move constructor, but am I *guaranteed* the move constructor?

I'm aware this is a silly example and that -- for example -- the copy constructor of this object should be deleted because there is no way to use it safely otherwise, but the semantics are simple enough that I wouldn't think something like this would be implementation-defined.

Comment: _"It doesn't seem to be the case."_ According to what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. There's nothing implementation-defined about it.

If there is a move constructor and it can be used, and it is a choice between a move constructor and a copy constructor, the move constructor will be invoked. That is a guarantee.

> `[C++11: 13.3.3.2/3]:` *[..]* Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if:
>
> *[..]*
>
> - S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference.
>
> *[..]*

I think your confusion stems from misuse of the term "elide". The compiler may elide copies/moves and replace them with *nothingness* — with in-place construction that bypasses the invocation of a constructor altogether. Copy elision never results in a move, and move elision never results in a copy. Either the object "transferral" happens or it does not.

You could sort of argue that your program has "implementation-defined" semantics in the sense that you don't know whether copies/moves *will* be elided until the program has been compiled, and because such elision is allowed to modify side-effects (such as console output). But we don't tend to think of it that way.

Regardless, this does not affect which of the copy and move constructors will be invoked if either are to be.

Your example is further flawed because only your move constructor *can* be invoked: your copy constructor takes a ref-to-non-`const` which can't be bound through an rvalue initialiser.